# building monitoring tool for azure using service management API

Tags: azure, cloud, monitoring

I am planning to design a tool to give monitoring info of azure hosted services etc. I like to know what are the security requirements for the same i.e. what kind of security certificates are needed.

In the first place is that possible(monitoring tool)...? to have an generic portal to get info based on your account details. If yes, what are required other than subscription ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Azure security certificate from your users, in order to connect to Azure Management API on their behalf.

---

Igor Papirov

Primary Architect of [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com)

Autoscaling and Monitoring solution for Windows Azure

Comment: In addition to the certificate, you'll need the private key (password) that goes along with the cert.